# Saying Hashem's name quickly in Hallel on Sukkos

Tags: shemos-sacred-names, sukkot, lulav-etrog-arba-minim, kavod, hallel

During Hallel on Sukkos, we [shake](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.651.8?p2=Mishnah_Berurah.651) the lulav during the הודו לה' כי טוב and אנא ה' הושיעה נא.  The standard practice I've seen is the one the Mishna Berurah describes there - one direction per word in הודו and two in אנא, except for Hashem's name.

Of course it's difficult to do that without streching out the words, especially נא.  The result sounds like

> Hooooooooooooduuuuuuuuuuuu <sup><sub>laHashem</sub></sup> kiiiiiiiiiiiiiii tooooooooooooov kiiiiiiiiiiii leooolaaaaaaaaaaam chaaasdoooooooooo
>
> Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaannaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa <sup><sub>Hashem</sub></sup> hooooooshiiiiiiiiaaaaa nnaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

The way it sounds always strikes me as odd.  Hashem's name sounds rushed in comparison to all the other words, and (this may be an illusion) chazzanim seem to rush it even more than is unavoidable by not stretching it out.

Would it be more respectful to say Hashem's name more slowly to avoid this effect?  Or, in the opposite direction, are you *supposed* to do it this way to avoid a hefsek in waving the lulav?  Or does it not matter?

Comment: I think there's some sort of problem with drawing out G-d's Name like that

Comment: @ezra even if you draw it out specifically to make it sound natural and match up with the rest of the words?

Comment: @ezra the Kohanim purposefully obfuscated God's name by extending it when blessing the people in the mikdash

Comment: @DoubleAA And too while saying Shema who doesn't elongate G-d's Name there?

Comment: +1 for the fun and accurate transliterations.

Comment: @Orangesandlemons in [kabbalistic] services with Kavanot, it is stretched out quite frequently.